# Number of affected Rows , SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have been reading some other topics releated to my problems but couldnt find a good answer , so I decided to writte my own .
The problem I am dealing with :

A java method that takes two parameters , Restaurant name and rateid.
This method update database (delete in this case) and return a boolean (true if delete was made and false if not found records to be deleted with specified condition) .

I though i could give value to this boolean by checking the numbers of rows affected , respectively : if the number of rows affected is 0 boolean value should be false , else it should be true .
But I am stucked in this part of code becouse I cant find a way to calculate the number of affected rows... 
The method  is down below :

```
public boolean deleteRate(String restaurantname,int rateid){
        boolean result = false;
        db = new Database();
        String updatesql ;

        updatesql = "delete from rate where  id = ? and restaurantname = ?";

    try{
        dbConnection = db.getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updatesql);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,rateid);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, restaurantname);
        db.setPreparedStatement(preparedStatement);
        int count = db.getPreparedStatement().executeUpdate();

        //System.out.println(count);
        if (count == 0 ){
            result = false;
        }

        else {
            result = true ;
        }

        recomputeAverageRate(restaurantname);

    }catch(SQLException ex){

    }

    return result ;

}
```

Everytime I make a delete the count number is equal to 0 .
Would be glad if I could get some help.
If there is a easier way or simple way or a different way to get the result I need I am open to all your suggestions ! 
Waiting for a response.
Thank you

Database table Rate tupples :

```
int Id primary key ,
int count ,
varchar comment , 
varchar restaurantname ,
varchar phone , 
varchar registrationtime
```

Comment: How is your database structured? Usually, id is a row identifier, so there should be no need to use any other columns for deleting when you have an id.

Comment: Id is primary key yes , but I also need restaurant name for another method , so I could change the updatesql  , thats not the problem , or is it ?? @Tobb

Comment: Which database, and which JDBC driver + version?

Comment: MySql database , and  My Sql JDBC Driver (testing localy at the moment) @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @ManishKothari Read the question than mark as duplicate . I've mentioned that I've read other topics aswell

Comment: @HasS you don't need anything other than id in your where-clause then. Because if the given restaurantName doesn't correspond to the given id, nothing will be deleted.

Comment: @Tobb thats the point , I dont want to delete any row without the second condition . . but thank you :)

Comment: What is the Object _Database_? Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: @HasS Ok, but having secondary conditions like that is a code smell in my book. Must mean you do not trust your input..

Comment: @Tobb There is nothing wrong with taking precautions when deleting things ;)

Comment: @NicolasFilotto hello nicolas , thanks for answering , attaching the tupples to my question in a moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some trying on my local code, and I got the expected result as you wish.

### Code:

```
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("drop table if exists rate; "
                    + "create table rate(id int, restaurantname varchar(20)); "
                    + "insert into rate values(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(1,'a')");
            preparedStatement.execute();

            String updatesql ;
            updatesql = "delete from rate where  id = ? and restaurantname = ?";
//          dbConnection = db.getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updatesql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1,1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "a");
//          db.setPreparedStatement(preparedStatement);
            int count = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            //System.out.println(count);
            boolean result = count > 0;
            System.out.println("count : " + count + ", result : " + result);
```

### Results:

```
count : 2, result : true
```

***Therefore, I think maybe the problem is in the data in table, not the java code.***

Comment: I will test in a few moments and give you and exact answer if works or not , ps thank you for answering to my topic :D

Comment: The solution you gave works perfectly  :)